# Multiplication table of a Galois group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm looking at the polynomial $x^4 − 4x^2 + 16$. I know that its roots are 
$1\pm\sqrt{3}$ and so its normal field extension is $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt{3})$.

However, I am also asked to give a multiplication table for the Galois group. What will that look like? What will be its rows and columns?)

(I am practicing for an exam)

Comment: Knowing that the roots can be expressed by radicals would tell you the Galois group is solvable of order four.  But you have identified only two of the roots (possibly a slight omission).

Comment: Those roots don't look correct.  I get $2 \pm 2 \sqrt{-3}$ as the roots of $u^2 - 4u + 16$.

Answer (score 1):

First, as @SpamIAm pointed out, the roots of $u^2-4u+16$ are $2\pm2\sqrt{-3}=4\omega^{\pm1}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive sixth root of unity, $\omega=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}2$. Thus the roots of your original polynomial are $\pm2\zeta^{\pm1}$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive twelfth root of unity. I think you can take it from here.